# Get Index of Current TabPage of PageControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I have AspxTabPageControl.. of Devexpress

I want to get the active tab index from Clientside(JavaScript) on `ButtonClientClick` Event..

how can i get it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

javascript

```
var index = tabcontrolname.GetActiveTabIndex();
```

this will give you current tabindex in Aspxtabview Control.

Answer (score 1):

control_name.GetActiveTab().index

Also you can investigate othe client side functionality
http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxTabControlScriptsASPxClientPageControlMembersTopicAll

Answer (score 1):

Use the client-side GetActiveTabIndex method:

```
<dx:ASPxPageControl ... ClientInstanceName="pc">
</dx:ASPxPageControl>


var index = pc.GetActiveTabIndex();
```

**See Also:**

[Tab Control - Client-Side Functionality](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxTabControlScriptsASPxClientPageControlMembersTopicAll)

[ASPxClientPageControl Members](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxTabControlScriptsASPxClientPageControlMembersTopicAll)